# How many 2 letter(Say r) words can be made using {a,a,a,a,b, c, d} elements? But,we can note that (n>r and r < number of similar letters)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, game-theory, computational-mathematics

we use this formula  "n!/p!.q!.r!" to compute permutation of n items containing p,q,n number of similar items, n= p+q+r+x (where x=n-(p+q+r)).

this formula stand true when length of permutation > max similar items i.e., Max(p,q,r).

but in the above problem we have permutation length as 2 which is < number of a's i.e, 4.

in such case how to compute permutation of items.

Comment: The answer will be the same as selecting from $\{a,a,b,c,d\}$

Comment: How many $2$ letter words can you make if both letters are different? How many can you make if they are same?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting 2 objects from {${a,a,a,a,b,c,d}$} will be the same as selecting two objects from {${a,a,b,c,d}$} because you don't actually get to see more than 2 $a's$ at a time.

From here you can either make cases or find the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expression

$2!(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})(1+x)^3$

Which comes out to be  13

Just for the sake of completeness here are the permutations

${aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,bc,bd,ca,cb,cd,da,db,dc}$